# What's the "Best Practice" approach for disabling secure pages on local Dev?

Tags: configuration

Wondering what the "best practice" approach would be for disabling secure pages on local dev. I'm running a site on Acquia Cloud and have access to the environment variable **AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT** and I could easily do something like:

```
if (isset($_ENV['AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT'])) {
  switch ($_ENV['AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT']) {
    // case 'dev':
    //   // do something on dev
    //   break;

    // case 'test':
    //   // do something on staging
    //   break;

    case 'prod':
      // do something on prod
      break;
  }
}
else {
    $conf['securepages_enabled'] = 0;
}
```

Is that the best approach or is there a better, cleaner way? Also, are there negative implications for filling up settings.php with stuff like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a best practice to create a `settings.local.php` file which is included at the end of the default `settings.php` file. Then within that file you can place whatever logic you want per server as you've done, or make the content of `settings.local.php` be specific per server host you're deploying too (and keep settings.local.php basically outside of version control).

This is a good practice for Drupal 7 development -- so good in fact Drupal 8 ships with such code in settings.php by default, which you can uncomment to make use of:

```
/** In settings.php for a drupal 8 site */

/**
 * Load local development override configuration, if available.
 *
 * Use settings.local.php to override variables on secondary (staging,
 * development, etc) installations of this site. Typically used to disable
 * caching, JavaScript/CSS compression, re-routing of outgoing emails, and
 * other things that should not happen on development and testing sites.
 *
 * Keep this code block at the end of this file to take full effect.
 */
# if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
#   include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
# }
```

Comment: But for an environment like Acquia Cloud, Where you are running one code-base without a local settings.php file capability, would this still hold up?

Comment: It's a feature supported by core drupal, I don't care what a 3rd party configuration supports personally. :). If anyone else has a work-around or suggestion for this specific use-case i'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to maintain separate site folders if you want different configs depending on the server role. In the simplest set-up, name each folder after the domain. Eg:

```
sites/
      dev.example.com/
          settings.php
      www.example.com/
          settings.php
```

If you need a more flexible mapping, you should use [sites.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/7) to hold the code used to determine which folder should apply.

Comment: Ops question had nothing todo with various sub-sites, but rather how to deal with Development, Staging and Production server settings configuration ...

Comment: You can use multiple sites for exactly this purpose, hence my answer.

Comment: oh i see what you're saying ...... ewww. This approach adds alot of folder noise to a drupal installation, there's only 1 site not a million requiring `sites.php` or drupal's multi-site configuration (which btw Drupal8 had rumors of removing -- but didn't for legacy reasons).

Comment: Matter of taste, I think :) I really do not like conditional logic in config files, it encourages kludges. Greatly prefer to keep them separate.